# CURL Script for "Map From Data Services" functionality in Couchabase analytics

Tags: shell, curl, scripting, couchbase

I am trying to create a script using CURL to map all collections present in a bucket.scope from data service to analytical service locally (Couchbase).

I have 50 odd collections created in my data node and now i need them in my analytics node (locally , no remote links).

suggest if any one has already done this.

P.S, No ChatGPT answers, tried them all not working.

Tried CBQ Commands, CLI commands, CURL commands. No Luck.

Hoping to acheive the same with any of the above.

Comment: Have you considered using one of the [Couchbase SDKs](https://docs.couchbase.com/home/sdk.html) to list the collections and set up the Analytics links?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a way to do this with a single cURL command, but you could do this with series of cURL commands orchestrated in a small bash script such as the example below:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=administrator
PASSWORD=password
COUCHBASE_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:8091
ANALYTICS_HOST=http://127.0.0.1:8095

BUCKET=$1
SCOPE=$2

if [ $# != 2 ]; then
  echo Usage: $0 \<bucket\> \<scope\>
  exit 1
fi

run_analytics () {
  echo Running "$*"
  curl -s -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD $ANALYTICS_HOST/analytics/service -d statement="$*" | jq '.errors[].msg' 2>/dev/null
}

echo Mapping $BUCKET.$SCOPE in Analytics

run_analytics CREATE ANALYTICS SCOPE \`$BUCKET\`.\`$SCOPE\` IF NOT EXISTS
run_analytics DISCONNECT LINK \`$BUCKET\`.\`$SCOPE\`.Local

for collection in $(curl -s -u $USERNAME:$PASSWORD $COUCHBASE_HOST/pools/default/buckets/$BUCKET/scopes | jq -r ".scopes[] | select(.name == \"$SCOPE\") | .collections[].name"); do
  run_analytics ALTER COLLECTION \`$BUCKET\`.\`$SCOPE\`.\`$collection\` ENABLE ANALYTICS
done

run_analytics CONNECT LINK \`$BUCKET\`.\`$SCOPE\`.Local
```

Note that there's no error handling, handling of funky bucket characters that would require URL encoding, etc. but hopefully this helps...